# Possibly duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion

There are three questions that are essentially about converting hand-written text to on-screen text.

[This](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7940/how-to-convert-handwriting-into-text) question has survived (i.e. not closed) and has answers. On the other hand, [this](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5937/software-that-converts-handwriting-to-computer-text) question was closed as being off-topic. Now, [this](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/what-is-a-good-ocr-program) third question is also similar and asks about OCR software recommendation.

However, at the base level, are they not the same? The heart of all three questions is: how do we convert hand written text to digital text?

In that light, should not all three of these be closed as being off-topic (and also being duplicates!)? Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The first two questions are dupes, no doubt about that.

For the third one, asking for OCR software, I'm not sure if it refers to hand writing even though I guess so.

Especially the last one (OCR software) is a list question and opinion based. It could be closed for that.

Are they off-topic? Well, we allow software questions if they are about special tools for writing. We also allow questions about editing. Scanning text on paper (handwritten or not) with an OCR software to edit/publish the text *could* be on-topic. Depends how the questions are asked.

I do not like the three questions, but I cannot nail it down why (besides being list/opinion based questions). But if in doubt I always vote for on-topic.

Comment: Yes, the OCR question does not explicitly mention hand writing but is pretty much evident that it talks about it. If we close one of these questions as being off-topic (the first one), then should we not follow suite and do the same for the rest of them?

Comment: @PraveshParekh, if one is off-topic, we can close all three, I agree. They are dupes or at least similar enough. But as I said, I'm not sure if they are off-topic.

Comment: All three of these are software recommendation questions, and off-topic. The third question is vaguely about journaling, but I think it's still a software recommendation at heart. Would be willing to close if there is no objection.

Comment: @NeilFein. no objection from my side.

Comment: I think I was misled by the title of the OCR one.  In my experience OCR usually refers to processing *typed* text, but the question is about handwriting, same as the other two.

Answer (score 2):

I share your (and Neil's and John's) reservations about these questions.  I think what *would* be on-topic is a question like the following:

> I have all these hand-written stories/journal entries/etc that I'd like to edit and publish.  What is the {easiest, cheapest, fastest... put criterion here} way to get this hand-written text into an editable digital form?

The question should focus on the *problem* (getting the text into the desired form), not the *means*.  Maybe, based on the volume, your best bet is to forget about software and just hire a teenager to type for you.  Answers can address the various options and their tradeoffs.

In my ideal world, somebody would ask a question like that, it would get useful answers, and then we'd close all these as duplicates of it.  Or maybe we'd merge some of these into it; I haven't reviewed all the answers.